# Connect to connman service using the first field rather than the second

Tags: connman

Given the following table

```
$ connmanctl services
*AO MyNetwork               wifi_dc85de828967_68756773616d_managed_psk
    OtherNET                wifi_dc85de828967_38303944616e69656c73_managed_psk 
    AnotherOne              wifi_dc85de828967_3257495245363836_managed_wep
    FourthNetwork           wifi_dc85de828967_4d7572706879_managed_wep
    AnOpenNetwork           wifi_dc85de828967_4d6568657272696e_managed_none
```

I'd like to be able to connect to a network, e.g. `OtherNET`, using the string `OtherNET` rather than the long `wifi_dc85de828967_38303944616e69656c73_managed_psk`, as I don't want to count the times I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> and/or check that the `wifi_` line in the prompt corresponds to the intended network.

Is this possible **with connman only**? Or do I really have to write a wrapper myself?

The `man` page of `connmanctl` contains

> ```
>    services
>           Shows a list of all available services. This  includes  the
>           nearby wifi networks, the wired ethernet connections, blue‐
>           tooth devices, etc.  An asterisk in front  of  the  service
>           indicates that the service has been connected before.
> ```

and

> ```
>    connect service
>           Connects  to  the  given  service. Some services need a so-
>           called provisioning file in order to connect to  them,  see
>           connman-service.config(5).
> ```

which both don't say much about the format of the output or the use of the command.

Similarly, the [wiki on Arch Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ConnMan#Connecting_to_an_open_access_point) refers to the last column as *the second field beginning with `wifi_`*.

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody has answered yet, I have found some spare time to code the following wrapper, which basically does the following

- keeps reading as long as the input is not `exit`;
- when an input is provided which starts with `connect`, the following word is used to pattern-match one line (only the first matching line) from `connman services`; the last field of this line (the one which starts with `wifi_`) is forwarded to `connmanctl connect`;
- any other non-empty input is forwarded to `connmanctl` as it is.
- a certain number (to be passed through the variable `NOINPUTS_BEFORE_EXIT` whose default is `3`) of empty inputs causes the script to `exit`.

The script is the following

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
name=$(basename $0)
noinputs_before_exit=${NOINPUTS_BEFORE_EXIT:=3}
while [[ $cmd != 'exit' ]]; do
  echo -n "$name " 1>&2
  read cmd
  if [[ -z "$cmd" ]]; then
    (( --noinputs_before_exit == 0 )) && exit
  else
    noinputs_before_exit=$NOINPUTS_BEFORE_EXIT
    if [[ $cmd =~ ^connect\  ]]; then
      connmanctl connect $(connmanctl services | awk '/'"${cmd#* }"'/ { print $NF; exit }')
    else
      connmanctl $cmd
    fi
  fi
done
```

The script limitations are at least the following:

- (less importantly, to me) I have no idea whether it meets any security requirements;
- it does not allow <kbd>Tab</kbd>-completion;
- (most importantly, to me) it does not use the `readline` library, so line editing impossible.